# ¿cómo solucionar problemas de memoria en r?

Tags: r, memoria

Estoy calculando puntajes de propensión con el comando ps del paquete twang. Son aproximadamente 30.000 individuos en 13 variables. El error dice: cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 GB.
He intentado aumentando memory.limit() y liberando memoria RAM en mi computador, pero no me da resultado.
Tengo un computador con 8GB de RAM, Windows de 64 bits. R versión 4.2 para 64 bits.

Comment: [Esto es lo que estás buscando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Si el problema es propio, es decir producto de un manejo poco óptimo de la memoria por el lado de tu Script, se puede solucionar corrigiendo esto, pero sin ver que es lo que estás haciendo, no hay forma de ayudarte. Ahora, si el problema no está en tú script, y simplemente estás trabajando con objetos muy grandes, no hay mucha alternativa más que conseguir más memoria para tu equipo o llevando el script a otra maquina incluso a una computadora en la nube que podrías dimensionar de acuerdo a tus necesidades.